# Suffix counterpart of klepto-?

Tags: greek, derivation, suffixes, neologism

I'm trying to come up with a suffix counterpart to the prefix *klepto-* (basically meaning "related to theft"), seeing that no such thing exists (and thus what I'm doing is technically neologism). For clarification, what I'm looking for is what the suffix *-phagy* is to the prefix *phago-*; both are from the same root, carry the same meaning, but are on opposite ends of the word and tend to have different functions (the prefix usually "X that eats"-type words, while the latter usually creates "X-eating"-type words).

One method that I've thought of to create the new suffix:

1. I looked for an Ancient Greek word that both derives from the same root as *klepto-* and is a noun that actually translates to "theft" (result: κλοπή *klopḗ*)
2. The way κλοπή sounded for some reason prompted me to look up the suffix *-trophy* on a hunch; and lo and behold, that one's Ancient Greek root is τροφή (*trophḗ*).
3. It thus seems logical to me that the hypothetical suffix counterpart of *klepto-* would be *-klopy*.

An alternative method: Following the example of *phago-*/*-phagy*, the suffix counterpart of *klepto-* would logically be *-klepty*.

Are either of these a sound derivation?

Comment: The root **cleps** is found in English "clepsydra" a water clock; and in Greek **clepsiphron** dissembling, untruthful; and **clepsicholos** pretending to be lame.  But the word for 'thievery' is not  *clepsis; instead it is  **cleptosune** so it doesn't form the obvious suffix '-clepsy.'

Comment: A suffix used with several dinosaur species is `-raptor` for "thief" or "taker", which may or may not serve depending on your needs, though not related to `klepto-`.

Comment: @Hugh: I cannot find anything about "cleptosune" besides this page.

Comment: @JonHanna: That's Latin, not Greek.

Comment: @MarqFJA87: I believe Hugh is referring to [κλεπτοσύνη](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dkleptosu%2Fnh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know any Greek. This is an answer based on Internet research (and now some helpful comments from Modern Greek speakers), not an expert answer. I would advise against accepting it or using it as the basis of any serious decision about forming a word.

- "-klopy"/"-clopy" seems most preferable to me in that there are at least two Greek words in the [LSJ dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Greek%E2%80%93English_Lexicon) ending in *-κλοπία* ([λογοκλοπία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlogoklopi%2Fa) "stealing of another's words" and [πυροκλοπία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dpuroklopi%2Fa) "theft of fire", which could be anglicized as "logoclopy" and "pyroclopy"). Although I can't find any compound words ending in *-κλοπή* in LSJ, Tasos Papastylianou and terdon have let me know that *-κλοπή* works as the second element of a compound word in Modern Greek. (The Modern Greek form of λογοκλοπία seems to be [λογοκλοπή](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%AE#Greek).) As I don't know Greek, I can't provide any explanation for the presence of the suffix *-ία* in the two Ancient Greek words mentioned above; I can only say that it seems to show up in some other old compound nouns referring to abstract concepts (e.g. *[ὑδροϕοβία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Du(drofobi%2Fa)* "hydrophobia", from *φόβος* "fear"; see Tasos Papastylianou's comments below for a native Greek speaker's perspective about the possible nuances of meaning the suffix *-ία* might add in this context.)

  In English, using the spelling "-klopy" rather than the less anglicized "-klopia" might allow you to maintain a touch of ambiguity about whether you intend for the word to be understood as derived from Greek *-κλοπία* or *-κλοπή*: because modern Greek *[κλοπή](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%80%CE%AE#Noun_2)* is pronounced as /kloˈpi/, with the vowel /i/, it is typically transcribed as "klopi", and "klopy" could perhaps be interpreted as a non-standard anglicization of this (with word-final letter "i" replaced with the letter "y" in accordance with usual English spelling conventions). There is some minor precedent for going from Greek *-ή* to English *-y* in the form of old spelling variants (or depending on your perspective, misspellings) of some words spelled in the current standard with "e", like "apostrophy", "epitomy". I dunno if that is really a convincing reason to choose this spelling, though. Maybe it's better to just make a definite decision (which might still be in favor of the spelling with "y", just not because of any ambiguity).

  (A side note on English pronunciation: it would be most regular to pronounce words ending in *-clopy/-klopy/-clope* with stress on the third-to-last syllable, following the [pattern of compound words like *miscroscopy, astronomy, geology*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194/how-are-words-ending-ology-onomy-ography-pronounced) or *syncope, apocope, apostrophe*).
- "-klepty" seems a bit more iffy to me, as I haven't been able to find any Greek words ending in *-κλεπτία.* However, terdon said in a comment below that *-κλεπτία* would work as the second part of a compound word in modern Greek.
  Whether or not it's sound in Ancient Greek, "-klepty" seems to have been used in modern scientific literature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karyoklepty.
- "-klepsy" is another one I'm unsure about, but would advise against using if you're trying to stick to Ancient Greek. *[κλεψιά](https://el.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%88%CE%B9%CE%AC)* does seem to exist in modern Greek (with stress on the last syllable, although the Greek Wiktionary says it would have been *κλεψία* in Medieval/Byzantine Greek) as some kind of synonym of *κλοπή,* but I don't know if it would be suitable for the purposes you describe. I didn't find any Greek compound words ending in *-κλεψία* in LSJ, and terdon said that, although *-κλεψιά* would work as the second element of a Modern Greek compound, it would be surprising if it existed in Ancient Greek. (Terdon also said that the difference between *κλεψιά* and *κλοπή* in modern Greeek is "akin to the difference between *theft* and *robbery* with the addition that *κλεψιά* also tends to be more colloquial.") I found some examples of "[χαρτοκλεψιά](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%CF%87%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%88%CE%B9%CE%AC&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)" used online in modern Greek (the first part of this word is from *χάρτης*; it seems to be related to *[χαρτοκλέφτης](http://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CF%87%CE%B1%CF%81%CF%84%CE%BF%CE%BA%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%86%CF%84%CE%B7%CF%82)* "card sharp/swindler").

With regard to scientific technical terms, while we can say that most of them are based on Ancient Greek and this is the principle for their derivation in an ideal kind of sense, in practice people derive them from whatever form of Greek they feel like using (or whatever they can find, or even from Latin instead of Greek). E.g. note that the linked Wikipedia article describes "karyoklepty" as being derived from "kleftis", which looks to me like it is a transcription of the Modern Greek pronunciation of the word for "thief" (*κλέφτης*; the ancient form of the word is *κλέπτης,*   which would be transliterated as "kleptes"). Since scientists  in the modern era don't usually study classical languages, it may be easier to check if a compound works in Modern Greek than to make sure it works in Ancient Greek.

Comment: Are you limiting this to Ancient Greek? The suffixes *-κλοπή*, *-κλεπτία* and *-κλεψιά* are common enough in Modern Greek. Or, at the very least, clearly understandable to any native speaker and would be immediately understood if added to a new word. PS. The difference between *κλεψιά* and *κλοπή* are akin to the difference between *theft* and *robbery* with the addition that *κλεψιά* also tends to be more colloquial.

Comment: Fair enough, I was wondering because you'd linked to a Modern Greek definition for *κλεψιά*, a word I'd be surprised to learn existed in Ancient.

Comment: I specifically ignored Modern Greek because AFAIK, scientists do so as well when coming up with new technical terms that are at least partially Greek. Otherwise, you'd be seeing them using "viology" instead of "biology".

Comment: @sumelic I'm a native speaker; I just know how to speak the thing, not the whys ;) In other words, yes there is absolutely a rule but I don't know it. As I recall it has something to do with the syllable that carries the stress, but I really can't tell you anything reliable.

Comment: If you're arguing semantics, the "clepto" in "cleptomaniac" implies "stealing" (i.e. verb form) not "theft" (i.e. noun form). The noun form would have been "clopemaniac" or something like that. Therefore, for an equivalent suffix I would go for the "klepty" (or "klepsy") instead, which is the equivalent 'verb' suffix. As for 'clopy', I would be a bit hesitant. Even if it appears in ancient texts as referenced above, the more typical ending should be 'clope' (κλοπή). I would assume that the 'y' ending refers to the «-ία» Greek ending equivalent.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: Thanks for the information about the meaning. Despite the title, I am not sure if MarqFJA87 actually wants an exact equivalent to klepto-, since the body of the question also says "related to theft" rather than "related to stealing". I think it might depend on the specific word that is being formed. As I don't know any Greek, I can't explain the use of ία in λογοκλοπία and πυροκλοπία. My impression is that it is similar to ὑδροϕοβία from φόβος; it looks like sometimes abstract compound nouns can get this suffix even it doesn't appear on the independent word

Comment: @sumelic I don't have a reference to back this up, and it's a subtle disctinction, but my intuitive feeling as a native speaker is that the ending «-ια» in such cases, denotes "a state of / tendency to", and that this tends to be transliterated as "-y". Hydrophobia is an interesting exception (in that it is not written "hydrophoby") but it is a good example nonetheless in that it denotes "a state of fear (of water)", as opposed to "Water-related fear".

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou: ... You do know that "stealing" can also be used as a noun rather than a verb, right? As for the "y" ending, I already gave an example in the OP where said ending represents ή (suffix -trophy derives from τροφή).

Comment: @MarqFJA87: while "-trophy" is derived from τροφή, the "-y" in the English word doesn't represent -ή directly: it represents the suffix -ία. E.g. "atrophy" comes from Greek *ἀτροϕία.*

Comment: @sumelic: Yeah, I know. I'm just saying that it's also used in the way I mentioned.

Comment: @MarqFJA87 no that's my point, and "-trophy" vs "-trophe" is another good example, from the greek word meaning "to feed / nourish / make grow". "Trophia" is a noun denoting the state of being fed, whereas "Trophe" is just the noun meaning "food". "Hypertrophy" refers to the state of being over-nourished. Similarly "Atrophy" is the state of lacking nourishment. Compare this with "Hypertrophe" (υπερτροφή) -- to a greek person this reads like "Superfood". Not like "overnourishment". Unfortunately this still doesn't shed any light as to whether the 'noun' form or the 'verb' form should be used.

Comment: As I point in my answer, klepsi- is absolutely an ancient root. I can't figure out why you'd caution against it.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: Because I don't understand the formation of compounds ending with "klepsia". My advice is, as I state at the start of the post, the advice of someone who doesn't know any Greek. So the only things I feel comfortable advising are things that I can see precedent for in Ancient Greek. I'm not trying to imply that I am actually qualified to judge that a certain formation is "incorrect"; but I can hardly recommend it if I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer: I might remove that sentence if you're sure "-klepsia" works in Ancient Greek; I added it in partly based on terdon's comment "κλεψιά, a word I'd be surprised to learn existed in Ancient." It's a bit hard for me to tell from your answer how -klepsia/-klepsy is formed from κλεψί-; as I said, I'm not at all qualified to say that it's wrong in Ancient Greek, but I'd feel more comfortable if I could see examples of parallel formations, or some reference to rules of compound formation that describe how it works. Is it a verb-final compound?

Comment: @sumelic That's a good point. I'll try to beef that up a bit.

Answer (score 2):

L/S has: βόο-κλεψ, contr. βοῦκλεψ, ὁ,

A stealer of oxen, S[ophocles].Fr[agment]318.